# Adding custom Reference to Asp.Net project and CHTML page does not see it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having some issues with a custom Reference. I created a new project and added the reference to the project and it seems to be working in the Models but when I try to use it in a CHTML page it does not seem to see it. I have had this issue before but not sure how I resolved it. If memory serves me correctly there is something in the project that needs to be selected or corrected.

This time around I found that if I put `@using MicrosoftHelper` on the page it is fine. In other projects I have, I do not need to do that. It is available for the whole project. I just cannot remember what I did to resolve it so I thought I might see if someone had any Ideas here.

MicrosoftHelper is the name of the Reference. So in a class if I use this for example its fine:

```
MicrosoftHelper.MSHelper.GetSiteRoot()
```

Part of the package is `StarkAjaxFormSubmiter` so if I use this in a CHTML Page I would do this:

```
@Html.StarkAjaxFormSubmiter("frmMenuPermission", "tbMenuPermission", true, "Action Successfully Executed")
```

In the Object Browser it has this:

```
MSHelper.StarkAjaxFormSubmiter(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, bool, string)
MSHelper.StarkAjaxFormSubmiter(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, bool, string, string)
MSHelper.StarkAjaxFormSubmiterSimple(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, string, string, string)
```

I did not write this so I have no idea how it works other than being an extension of `System.Web.Mvc`

To my knowledge I have went through what i think is everything that i need to do to add a referance but i have to be missing something if it is not available to the entire project.

I have cleaned and rebuilt several times, closed Visual Studio and even rebooted My PC.

Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution. I dont know why but when I post on here It gives me other ideas of what it could be. Simple solution. I did not add it to the Web.config in the View folder.

```
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="BaseProject" />
    <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html" />
    <add namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" />
    <add namespace="MicrosoftHelper" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```